# Why Gitlab-CI sometimes creates project directory with root owner (but i have specified another user) and how to solve it?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I setup Gitlab CI/CD for my test project. I use docker containers with `postgres` and `go` and sometimes I need to change sql init script (which creates tables in database), so I use these commands:

1. `docker-compose stop`
2. `docker system prune`
3. `docker system prune --volumes`
4. `sudo rm -rf pay`
5. then on my PC I push changes to Gitlab and it runs pipelines

But sometimes after step 5 Gitlab-CI throws me a `permission denied error` on `deploy` step (see below) as it creates pay directory with root owner.

Here is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - tools
  - build
  - docker
  - deploy

variables:
  GO_PACKAGE: gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_PATH
  REGISTRY_BASE_URL: registry.gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_PATH

# ######################################################################################################################
# Base
# ######################################################################################################################

# Base job for docker build and push in private gitlab registry.
.docker:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: docker
  variables:
    IMAGE_SUBNAME: ''
    DOCKERFILE: Dockerfile
    BUILD_CONTEXT: .
    BUILD_ARGS: ''

  script:
    - adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" builder
    - su -l builder
    - su builder -c "whoami"
    - echo "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin registry.gitlab.com
    - IMAGE_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    - IMAGE=${REGISTRY_BASE_URL}/${IMAGE_SUBNAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}
    - docker build -f ${DOCKERFILE} ${BUILD_ARGS} -t ${IMAGE} ${BUILD_CONTEXT}
    - docker push ${IMAGE}
  tags:
    - docker


# ######################################################################################################################
# Stage 0. Tools
#
# ######################################################################################################################

# Job for building base golang image.
tools:golang:
  extends: .docker
  stage: tools
  variables:
    IMAGE_SUBNAME: 'golang'
    DOCKERFILE: ./docker/golang/Dockerfile
    BUILD_CONTEXT: ./docker/golang/
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
#    changes:
#      - docker/golang/**/*


# ######################################################################################################################
# Stage 1. Build
#
# ######################################################################################################################

# Job for building golang backend in single image.
build:backend:
  image: ${REGISTRY_BASE_URL}/golang
  stage: build
  # TODO: enable cache
#  cache:
#    paths:
#      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/backend/vendor

  before_script:
    - cd backend/

  script:
    # Install dependencies
    - go mod download
    - mkdir bin/

    # Build binaries
    - CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags '-static' -s -w" -o bin/backend ./cmd/main.go

    - cp -r /usr/share/zoneinfo .
    - cp -r /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt .
    - cp -r /etc/passwd .
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 30min
    paths:
      - backend/bin/*
      - backend/zoneinfo/**/*
      - backend/ca-certificates.crt
      - backend/passwd
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
#    changes:
#      - backend/**/*
#      - docker/golang/**/*


# ######################################################################################################################
# Stage 2. Docker
#
# ######################################################################################################################

# Job for building backend (written on golang). Only change backend folder.
docker:backend:
  extends: .docker
  variables:
    IMAGE_SUBNAME: 'backend'
    DOCKERFILE: ./backend/Dockerfile
    BUILD_CONTEXT: ./backend/
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
#    changes:
#      - docker/golang/**/*
#      - backend/**/*


# ######################################################################################################################
# Stage 3. Deploy on Server
#
# ######################################################################################################################

deploy:dev:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    SERVER_HOST: 'here is my server ip'
    SERVER_USER: 'here is my server user (it is not root, but in root group)'
  before_script:
    ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

    ## Run ssh-agent
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

    ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV variable to the agent store
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null

    ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

    ## Enable host key checking (to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks)
    - ssh-keyscan $SERVER_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

    ## Git settings
    - git config --global user.email ""
    - git config --global user.name ""

    ## Install rsync if not already installed to upload files to server.
    - 'which rsync || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install rsync -y )'
  script:
    - rsync -r deploy/dev/pay $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_HOST:/home/$SERVER_USER/dev/backend
    - ssh -tt $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_HOST 'cd dev/backend/pay && ./up.sh'
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
```

I have already tried to turn off change triggers and clear gitlab container registry, but it didn't help.

Also I have found interesting thing, that when tools pipeline starts (it is the first pipeline) at that moment my server immediately creates pay folder with root owner and empty sub-folders.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hey there—GitLab team member here: I am looking into your post to help troubleshoot your issue. [Linked here is a doc on what to do when you encounter Permissions Problems with GitLab+Docker.](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#permission-problems)

It's likely that you have tried some of these steps, so please let me know! I'll keep researching while I wait to hear back from you. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I have looked the link you had posted, but it couldn't help me. Actually, I don't use `gitlab docker image`. Also I use shared runners. To clarify the situation here is a link to my post (it is all about the same problem): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216680/every-time-gitlab-ci-recreates-directory-it-becomes-owned-by-root Hope to get help from you, thanks!